# HP P160 Sata Power to PCIe Power

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hp

My HP ProDesk 400 G9 sff has a 6-pin power output (P160 SATA Power) on its motherboard to deliver power to HDDs and other SATA devices. I wanted to know if it's possible to use this socket, with some modding, to deliver power to a discrete GPU. The power supply is rated for 240W, and the CPU is rated at 65W. I believe there is plenty left that could be used to operate a 100-120W discrete GPU.

I've come across SATA cables to PCIe 6-8 pins online, but I'm wondering why not utilize the pinout on the motherboard directly instead of adding a potential weak link in the middle?

I'm aware that SATA power is rated to deliver 54W, and this board has 2 SATA ports, plus one that isn't soldered (the 600 variants have it soldered). Given all of this, theoretically, it should be able to output at least 54W x 2 = 108W

I don't have a multimeter to verify the pinout voltage, but since it's SATA, and the cable that goes into this is color-coded, it should have these voltages

[image]

Comment: Something to consider is '240w' is across all the voltage rails, and some cheaper PSUs split 12 v rails to two (or more?) Different rails. 'I'm wondering why not utilize the pinout on the motherboard directly instead of adding a potential weak link in the middle?' Cause the OEM doesn't expect you to do that, and most people are not going to extensively modify a rebuilt SFF PC for a medium to high power GPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pinout of the P160 SATA PWR0 connector for the HP ProDesk 400 G9 SFF motherboard is as follows.

**12V | GND | 5V

5V  | GND | 12V**

Tested with a multimeter by me, https://youtu.be/jjxTXR4IwG0

After speaking with HP support, I ended up with an engineer and he stated the following.

The cable that comes from factory with the port for this model uses both GND pins and 1x 12V and 1x 5V pins rated for 54W over 12V and 22W over 5V.

There are other variants of the cable that uses 6 pins and has other SATA connector configurations.

**It's 54W per 12V and 22W per 5V, giving a total of 108W over 12V and 44W over 5V combined**.

The system is aware of the maximum load for the port, and it has an overload protection. Similar to the total system power limitation mentioned below.

Other useful information:

- The factory cable used for this port is M90949-001 CA 2235 Rev. A.
- This motherboard has a very nice total system power limitation; I have the 180W PSU variant with part number M76038-001 and I ran a power test with OCCT for an hour peaking at 180.3W with an Intel i5-12500 and a NVIDIA RTX A2000 6GB, I have lifted the PL1 and PL2 CPU limits for this test and some kind of internal voltage limit is triggered throttling the CPU power draw in favor of the GPU one, so the GPU always works at max load and the system never goes beyond 180~W staying stable without crashes.

Comment: Was this supposed to be an answer?  If so, why are looking for guidance?

Comment: He also needed to know the voltages, and with some help we can get to the solution by testing so I can update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a full answer, I would still like some guidance on how to test it and see if the port can handle the maximum load.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for digging up this info. After putting some more thought into this mod, I've shifted my idea towards modding the main power cable on the PSU. That cable is capable of delivering 216W, which should be enough for a RTX 4060.

Answer (score 1):

According to the
[manual](https://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c08017709),
the power supply is rated as able to run with the
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 8GB GDDR6 Graphics Card with a power consumption
of 120W.

It seems like there is enough power to run a discrete GPU, if you're
not already using it all up with an NVIDIA RTX.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the 3050 is compatible with the Tower variant, mine is SFF, small form factor

Comment: There are several possible configurations for your model with different power draw figures. You might try to use a power calculator to see if your PSU is sufficient, for example [OuterVision](https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator). These numbers are only approximations, but they'll give you an idea of the possibilities.